# How can I tell if the AC is discharged?

Tags: ford, ac

Title basically says it all.  I need to convert from R12 to R134, and was told that the ac was discharged when I bought the truck, but I want to double check.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming everything is hooked up properly, try turning on the A/C to the max. If it's weak or non-existent, it's got no pressure to work with.

Comment: Got it fully charged.  still no cold air unfortunately :(  will have to see if I can do anything else, othrwise, will just have to take it in.

Comment: Is the compressor kicking in?

Comment: Looks like it kicks on and then off after a couple of seconds.  no real work being done.